# Cursor drifts in Qt 4 application, how do I debug it?

Tags: c++, qt4.8

I work on a large application with a Qt 4 GUI. On one of my Windows' PCs I get a cursor drifting away when this application is running. The cursor starts moving on its own in some direction (top to bottom or diagonally) steadily, linear, without changes of the direction. I can move it with my mouse but it continues the drift once I stop resist it. This starts in a random moment of time: it can start right at the moment I run the application or after several minutes of a normal work.

Honestly, I don't have a clue how to start with debugging such an issue. Can anyone be so kind to give me a clue on where to start, a place to stand so I can move this stone?

To make it clear, I have access to the source code of the application, I can compile a debug version of Qt libraries as well, if there is such a need.

Comment: I don't know how to debug this, but just to clarify, by cursor you mean the mouse cursor? As opposed to the text cursor marking the current input position in a text field. Also, can you rule out this is a hardware issue, i.e. a faulty mouse?

Comment: Yes, this is a mouse cursor. The mouse itself is fine, because I get this issue on in this application. I run all othere apps (including some other qt 4.8 applications) without any problems.